# Why is my form not being saved to admin database?

Tags: python, django, ajax

I'm trying to develop a website for an online store using Django. I want to use Ajax to handle the view of my  checkout form after it has been submitted. After the form is submitted, I want it to go to :

`return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse(str(next_page))+"?address_added=True")`, i.e http://127.0.0.1:8000/checkout/?address_added=True

But for some reason, it is not going there. Rather it's being redirected to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/checkout/?csrfmiddlewaretoken=W4iXFaxwpdtbZLyVI0ov8Uw7KWOM8Ix5GcOQ4k3Ve65KPkJwPUKyBVcE1IjL3GHa&address=123+Main+Street&address2=&state=MA&country=USA&zipcode=55525&phone=%28877%29+314-0742&billing=on`

As a result, the form data is also not getting saved. I was thinking if it were because of the new version of Django.

What I want to do is that after they submit the place order button, the form is going to be None, i.e disappear and then I would add a credit card form there for payment. But it is not happening. What is wrong here? How can I do this, or is there a better way to do this?

My forms.py:

```
class UserAddressForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = UserAddress
        fields = ["address", "address", "address2", "state", "country", "zipcode", "phone", "billing"]
```

My accounts.views.py:

```
def add_user_address(request):
    try:
        next_page = request.GET.get("next")
    except:
        next_page = None
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = UserAddressForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            new_address = form.save(commit=False)
            new_address.user = request.user
            new_address.save()
            if next_page is not None:
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse(str(next_page))+"?address_added=True")
        else:
            raise Http404
    else:
        raise Http404
```

My orders.views.py:

```
@login_required()
def checkout(request):
    try:
        the_id = request.session['cart_id']
        cart = Cart.objects.get(id=the_id)
    except:
        the_id = None
        return redirect(reverse("myshop-home"))

    try:
        new_order = Order.objects.get(cart=cart)
    except Order.DoesNotExist:
        new_order = Order(cart=cart)
        new_order.cart = cart
        new_order.user = request.user
        new_order.order_id = id_generator()
        new_order.save()
    except:
        return redirect(reverse("cart"))


    try:
        address_added = request.GET.get("address_added")
    except:
        address_added = None 

    if address_added is None:
        address_form = UserAddressForm()
    else:
        address_form = None

    if new_order.status == "Finished":
        #cart.delete()
        del request.session['cart_id']
        del request.session['items_total']
        return redirect(reverse("cart"))


    context = {"address_form": address_form, "cart": cart}
    template = "orders/checkout.html"
    return render(request, template, context)
```

My urls.py:

```
path('ajax/add_user_address', accounts_views.add_user_address, name='ajax_add_user_address'),
```

My checkout.html:

```
<form method="POST" action="{% url 'ajax_add_user_address' %}?redirect=checkout">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <fieldset class="form-group">   
        {{ address_form|crispy }}
    </fieldset>
    <div class="form-group">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-dark" type="submit" id="button">Place Order</button>
    </div>
</form>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#button").click(function(){
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "{% url 'ajax_add_user_address' %}",
        data: {
          "csrfmiddlewaretoken": "{{ csrf_token }}",
        },
        success: function(data){
          console.log("success!"),
        },
        error: function(data){
          console.log("error"),
        },
      });
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: @zack turners answer is correct.

Comment: I did add the models to my admin.py file @andypaling1

Comment: I see quite a lot of mistakes in your code, but the first one is your JavaScript. You're not doing event.preventDefault() and you're not including form data in the request (which is not submitted with Ajax in the first place)

Comment: Can you please show me the correct way to do it?

Comment: Wilful and time-wasting self duplicate: [Why is my form not being saved to my Django database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61317107/why-is-my-form-not-being-saved-to-my-django-database)

Comment: This question appears in a sequence of 11 questions from the same author on the same, or nearly the same topic. Many of these are copy-paste duplicate of each other, and will serve to waste the time of helpful readers who have not checked how many times the question has been re-asked.

Answer (score 1):

Have you added it to the admin.py file like this:

```
admin.site.register(Name of Model)
```

Comment: Yess I have added it

Comment: What else could be wrong here??

Comment: have you made migrations

Comment: Yes I have made migrations